# div container should fill 100% of website

Tags: html, css, height, styling

Hey I am currently working on a little website. By now I have a header, which is already working fine.

I only have problems with my divs for the content.

I am trying to make the content fill up the site 100% on the y-axis.
For this I used height:100%;

Unfortunately the div doesn't fill everything when there's more text in it and you can scroll down.

Does anyone know how to make the div expand ?!

Sry that I could format the question better, the problem's hard to explain.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: #F2F2F2; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: expresswayregular;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'expresswayregular';
    src: url('fonts/expressway_rg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/expressway_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#header {
 position: fixed;
 background: #333333;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 top: 0;
}

#header-content {
 background: #333333;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
}

#profile {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 100px;
}

#profile-icon {
 position: absolute;
 top: 7.5px;
 left: 0;
}

#profilename {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 110px;
 height: 20px;
 margin-left: 36px;
 padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#profilename:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #2997D3;
 transition: all 300ms;
}

#button-profile {
 width: 100px;
 height: 20px;
}

#sections_panel{
 position: absolute;
 background: #333333;
 height: 0px;
 width: 140px;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1000;
 transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}

#sections_panel  div{
 background:#333;
 padding: 6px;
 height: 238px;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #FC0;
}

#search-box {
 position: absolute;
 background: #333333;
 margin-left: 250px;
}

#search {
 position: absolute;
 background: #fff;
 width: 412px;
 height: 16px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 padding: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px; 
}

#submit {
 position: absolute;
 background: #fff;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 476px;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0; 
}

#menu {
 margin-right: 50px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.menu-linkbox *{
 position: static;
 float: right;
 width: auto;
 height: 14px;
 top: 0;
 padding: 18px 15px 18px 15px;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu-linkbox:hover a {
 color: #2997D3;
 transition: all 500ms;
}

#main-content {
 background: #fff;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding-top: 50px;
 display: block;
}

#content-articles {
 background: #F2F2F2;
 width: 1220px;
 height: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: visible;
}

#article1 {
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
}

#article2 {
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
}

#article3 {
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
}

#article4 {
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
}

#player {
 background: #333333;
 position : fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

#player-content {
 background: #333333;
 width: auto;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 font-size: 25px;
 
}

h1 {
 color: #2997D3;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

p {
 margin: 20px;
 
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <head> 
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  
  <title>SleekPlayer</title>
  
  <script>
   function toggleNavPanel(x){
    var panel = document.getElementById(x), navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"), maxH="300px";
    if(panel.style.height == maxH){
     panel.style.height = "0px";
     navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9662;";
    } 
   
    else {
     panel.style.height = maxH;
     navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9652;";
    }
   }
  </script>
 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <div id="header">
  
   <div id="header-content">
  
    <img id ="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
    
    <div id="profile">

     <img id ="profile-icon" src="images/profile-icon.png" />
    
     <div id="profilename" onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')">
    
      <div id="button-profile"> Profilename <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></div>
    
     </div>
     
     <div id="sections_panel">
      
      <div>
       
      </div>
      
     </div>
    
    </div>
   
    <div id="search-box">
   
     <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   
      <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Suche">
   
      <input id="submit" type="image" src="images/search.png" alt="Submit">
   
     </form>
   
    </div>
    
    <div id="menu">     
     
     <div class="menu-linkbox"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Aktuelles</a></div>
      
     <div class="menu-linkbox"><a href="https://google.de/">Neues</a></div> 

     <div class="menu-linkbox"><a href="https://facebook.com/">Interessantes</a></div>

     <div class="menu-linkbox"><a href="https://twitter.com/">Allgemeines</a></div>
     
    </div>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div id="main-content">
  
   <div id="content-articles">
   
    <div id="article1"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
    <div id="article2"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="article3"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
     
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
    <div id="article4"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
 <!--
  <div id="player">
   
   <div id="player-content">
   
   
   
   </div> 

  </div>
 -->
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to better understand what you're trying to do. You want the `#main-content` and `#content-article` to take up the full height of the browser, minus the `header`, and you want the content to scroll within `#main-content`, rather than having the whole browser window scroll?

Comment: Not quite. I want the header to be fixed. The #main-content to be behind the header and taking height: 100% and the #content-articles to fill up the #main-content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at this [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVDXQ/599/)

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
.container {min-height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Idk why you downvote this, as this is the solution the poster is looking for -.-

Comment: Thanks I think it worked (thumbs up) btw I dont know why you'd downvote either

Comment: @Miestiec Glad I could help :D an upvote would be nice xD
If this solves your problem please accept an the answer to mark the post as solved.